# M1- How to Properly Enable Full Site HTTPS?

Tags: magento-1.9

I need advice as I have found mixed suggestions on how to Properly change site to FULL-HTTPS (frontend and backend).

I have set "YES" for both "Use  Secured URL's in Frontend and Admin", but the site still loads as http:// with the exception of admin and checkout pages, they are https://.

Now I am thinking, in the **Unsecured Section**: Should I change base url from http:// to https:// ?

As well, should I also change the following unsecured values to Secured?

{{unsecure_base_url}}

{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/

{{unsecure_base_url}}media/

{{unsecure_base_url}}js/

Finally, how to properly redirect google traffic so that all http://example.com/baseballhat, 
 links redirected to secured version 
https://example.com/baseballhat, 
rather than to the secured homepage https://example.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you change the protocol for the unsecure Base URL to `https`. You do not need to change the other unsecure Base URLs (for Link, Skin, or Media), because it's using a shortcode variable that uses whatever you have configured for `Base URL`.

Here is how we have it configured:

[image]

As for maintaining your page rank on Google:

**NGINX** - Add the following to your Nginx config.

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
 return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

**Apache** - Add the following to your .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Note: mod_rewrite must be enabled on the Apache server.

Comment: Thanks so much! What about proper redirect of all google links from http to https ?

Comment: @Icon - Sorry I missed that last bit. See my updated answer.

Comment: I have one more question, in the Auto-redirect to Base URL section, should i enable 301, 302 or set as No?

Comment: @icon Maybe someone else will chime in if they have anything to add, but we set this to `No`, otherwise Magento seems to redirect `non-www URL's` to the homepage.